# Extract exactly n digits in a sentence using REGEX

Tags: java, regex

Example

> The no.s 1234 65

Input: `n`

For `n=4`, the output should be `1234`

For `n=2`, the output should be : `65` (not 12)

Tried `\d{n}` which gives `12` and `\d{n,}` gives `1234` but i want the exact matching one.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("//\d{n,}");
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please state an example input and the expected output for it

Comment: You can try something like [^\d]\d{2} if the input in the question is really like what you are working on.

Answer (score 2):

you need negative lookaround assertion: `(?<!..)`: negative look behind, and `(?!..)`: negative look ahead : [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BTSNPV/1)

```
(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)
```

however not all regex engine supports them, maybe a work around may match also the preceeding character and following character (contrary to look-around which are 0 width matches), (`\D` matches all excpet a digit)

```
(?:^|\D)(\d{4})(?:\D|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't code in java but I can try to answer this using regex in general.

If your number is in the format `d1d2d3d4 d5d6` and you want to extract digits `d5d6`, create 3 groups as `r'([0-9]+)("/s")([0-9]+)'` – each set of parenthesis () represent one group. Now, extract the third group only in another object which is your required output.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you meant is the `\b` character.

Hence, the regex you're looking for would be (for `n=2`):

```
\b\d{2}\b
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're looking for a regex that will match a number in a string which has n digits, taking into into account the spacing between the numbers. If that's the case, you're looking for something like this:

```
\b\d{4}\b
```

The \b will ensure the match is constrained to the start/end of a 'word' where a word is the boundary between anything matched by \w (which includes digits) and anything matched by the opposite, \W (which includes spaces).